# init value with ng-model/ng-init in simple_form collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I've got `simple_form_for @tag` in `#edit` action and one of the field is

`<%= f.input :color, collection: %(red green blue), input_html: {ng_model: 'colorBoxValue'} %>`.

Unfortunately after form is rendered `ng-model ColorBoxValue` is `undefined`. After I select any of option, `ng-model` is being set up properly.

What I want to achieve is to have `ng-model ColorBoxValue` set up properly before I choose any of option (but remember that `simple_form_for @tag` is in `#edit` action so `@tag` comes with value (one of these: red/green/blue) from database so I **can't** hardcode `ng-init` on static value...). It should get `selected` item which comes from database

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this might be an outdated issue for you but i am writing for other people who is looking for solution.

may be this could work: in angular controller setting $scope.colorBoxValue to default color from database